# pine script - plot triangle if condition is true 2 times in previous 6 candles

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to plot a triangle if within the previous 6 candlesticks, there are at least 2 times where a moving crossover occurs. I have the following script but i don't know how to code the if statement. thanks alot in advance for any advice!

```
//@version=4
study(title="Crossover", overlay=true,resolution="")

first = ema(close, 5)
seconds = ema(close, 13)
third = sma(close,21)
fourth = sma(close,34)
fifth = sma(close, 55)
sixth = sma(close,89)


plot(first, title="EMA 5", color=color.red, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(seconds, title="Ema 13", color=color.aqua, linewidth=1, transp=0)
plot(third, title="SMA 21", color=color.orange, linewidth=2, transp=0)
plot(fourth, title="SMA 34", color=color.blue, linewidth=2, transp=0)
plot(fifth, title="SMA 55", color=color.black, linewidth=2, transp=0)
plot(sixth, title="SMA 89", color=color.purple, linewidth=2, transp=0)


long1 = (first > seconds) and crossover(first,third)
long2 = (first > third) and crossover(first, seconds)
long3 = (first > fourth) and (first > seconds) and (first > third) and cross(first,fourth)


// if long1 or long2 or long3 is true 2 times in the previous 6 six candles then plot it ("long")
xxxxxx


plotshape(series=long, title="L", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text="L", size=size.small)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`barssince`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_barssince) function:

```
LENGTH = 6

count1 = barssince(long1 or long2 or long3)
count2 = count1[count1 + 1]

plotshape(count1 + count2 < LENGTH - 1, title="L", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text="L", size=size.small)
```

UPDATE

Actually, my solution is a bit over-designed, and I would recommend [`sum`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_sum) as suggested by Bjorn Mistiaen:

```
LENGTH = 6    

count = sum(long1 or long2 or long3 ? 1 : 0, LENGTH)

plotshape(count >= 2, title="L", style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, text="L", size=size.small)
```

Answer (score 2):

See [How can I count the occurrences of a condition in the last x bars?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-condition-in-the-last-x-bars) for an example.